# PHP function with parameter set by link

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

say for instance i have the following method

```
    public function admin_edit($id = null)
{
    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $this->redirect('/Organizations/admin_index');
    }

   $this->set(array('org'=>$this->getModel('Organization')->find($id)));
   $this->setLayout('admin_layout');

}
```

Now i wish to call this function and set the `$id` variable = to 1

so in HTML i create the following link:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="/Organizations/admin_edit?id=1">Edit</a>
```

However this only creates a `$_GET` variable called `id` and sets it to `1`

Is there a way to call functions where you set the parameter in the link?

Comment: `$obj->admin_edit($_GET['id']);`

Comment: Yeah i know i can do it in PHP afterwards but i am looking for a solution where you don't have to. The question is if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some php logic to load the correct function, some kind of basic routing, as you can not directly call a function from a url (which is good, just think what a security nightmare that would be).

Something like this:

```
$func = isset($_GET['func']) ? $_GET['func'] : '';
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

switch($func){
    case 'func1':
         function_one($id);
         break;
    case 'func2':
         function_two($id);
         break;
    default:
         //handle incorrect
}
```